# How to get stream to "in-memory" database created via H2DB?

Tags: java, database, stream, h2

I have to create such a mechanism:

1. Create in-memory (H2DB) database;
2. Create tables and fill them using some data;
3. Get stream to that database;
4. Send that stream via WebDAV or something else;

I know everything except that "How to get stream to "in-memory" database created via H2DB"?

---

And some explanations:

- I can't create file because of some server restrictions;
- I need that stream to create a file;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the SQL script from a database using [org.h2.tools.Script.execute(String url, String user, String password, OutputStream out)](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Script.html#execute_String_String_String_OutputStream). This works even for in-memory databases.

You can use the so called '[in-memory file system](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#file_system)'. To get the file as a stream, you would need to use the internal H2 file API however (org.h2.IOUtils.openFileInputStream).

Comment: Thanks for the link to file-system options. Not related to this question but I found the nioMapped FileSystem to be orders of magnitude faster for my 300MB dataset.

Answer (score 0):

[H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) supports [In-Memory Databases](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases) using the database URL `jdbc:h2:mem:`.

Addendum: Once you connect to the database, you can submit queries using [jdbc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) to obtain the desired data. `DatabaseMetaData` may be useful for comprehensive access. The streaming format will depend on the intended target.

Comment: Yes, I know how to create database and how to manipulate it. But I don't know how to "dump" database to stream and send that stream to another app.

Comment: I've elaborated above. Can you clarify "dump" and "stream" in this context?